# How to add variable int a chained call to object?

Tags: javascript

If I have

```
obj1.obj2.obj3
```

and I want to refer to any of them with a variable

```
var x = obj2
```

how should i use it to call obj2, since `obj1.x.obj3` obviously doesn't work

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This way

```
var x = obj1.obj2;
x.obj3;
```

Or this way

```
var x = 'obj2';
obj1[x].obj3;
```